# Smoothing in python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, smoothing

I am using Naive Bayes classifier in python for text classification. Is there any smoothing methods to avoid zero probability for unseen words in python NLTK? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to replace all the words with low (specially 1) frequency to `<unseen>`, then train the classifier in this data. 
For classifying you should query the model for `<unseen>` in the case of a word that is not in the training data.